# Convert date and time to milliseconds in Android

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have **Date** and **Time** from **`DatePicker`** and **`TimePicker`**. Now i want to change the selected date and time into **milliseconds**. How can I do this???

For Example I have **Date** selected **`2-5-2012`** and **Time** is **`20:43`**

Now I have to convert this Date Time into **milliseconds** something like

**DateTimeInMilliseconds** = **`1234567890`**

Comment: do you mean milliseconds passed since 00:00 January 1st 1970?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can create a Calendar object with the values from your DatePicker and TimePicker:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 
             timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: I like your approach (+1) but I personally avoid the try-catch block overhead whenever possible. Will `"d-M-yyyy"` work for double digit dates, like "12-10-2012"?

Comment: But he just needs the time in milliseconds, nothing more. So there is  overhead because first you get the actual time, then you reset it and only after that you get your milliseconds while there is a Date object that has the getTime() method that returns the milliseconds immediatly.

Comment: @Sam Yes. `d` accepts "1-31", `dd` accepts "01-31", same applies for `M` and `MM`.

Comment: @JonathanCruz Yes, there is a small waste there. But where are you getting your Date object from? For a reason I don't know, there is no direct method to get a Date value from a DatePicker.

Comment: @krunalshah Don't make such useless edits. Adding the `TimePicker` does not improve the answer one bit, that just adds information which has nothing to do with the answer itself. I already rolled your edit back.

Comment: @XaverKapeller, right but i was targeting fresher in android, they become confused with timepicker reference like how it come in declare code and how to initialize so i did.

Answer (score 11):

Merge the two strings together, and parse them using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Something like this:

```
String toParse = myDate + " " + myTime; // Results in "2-5-2012 20:43"
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy hh:mm"); // I assume d-M, you may refer to M-d for month-day instead.
Date date = formatter.parse(toParse); // You will need try/catch around this
long millis = date.getTime();
```

Sample on IDEOne: http://ideone.com/nOJYQ4

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code

```
String string_date = "12-December-2012";

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date d = f.parse(string_date);
long milliseconds = d.getTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `getTime()` method of the `Date` class returns a `long` with the time in milliseconds.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html

So if you have a Date object somewhere like:

```
Date date;
```

You can do:

```
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

And it will print out the time in milliseconds.