# How do I get the current time in milliseconds from a timepicker in android?

Tags: android

I need to get the time in milliseconds from the timepicker, so that later I can check it with the current time, in order to carry out some activity.
Any help.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223203/convert-date-and-time-to-milliseconds-in-android

Comment: there are only hour and minute field in a time picker. the remained parts (second and millisecond) of the picked time will be zero. isn't it?

Comment: No i need to get the time in milliseconds from a normal timepicker,  @ShabbirDhangot

Comment: @alijandro Yes you are right

Comment: Is that not the answer you want? millisecond is zero, no needing to get again.

Comment: No I want it in the format of getCurrentTimeMillis() function, @alijandro

Comment: This will help you to get seconds.https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I want to check the current time in a service with the picked time, any help?

Comment: I suggest you to skip milliseconds. because Time picker is not specially made for the milliseconds.

Comment: ok ill try to avoid milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

```
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }
    }, 10, 20, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String dateInString = "22-01-2015 10:20:56";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

System.out.println(dateInString);
System.out.println("Date - Time in milliseconds : " + date.getTime());

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println("Calender - Time in milliseconds : " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Output :

```
22-01-2015 10:20:56
Date - Time in milliseconds : 1421893256000
Calender - Time in milliseconds : 1421893256000
```

Comment: take date-time from your picker and convert it into milliseconds as described above.